# Corrosion rate of a metal in a liquid in relation to the size of electric current

Tags: electrochemistry, water, metal

I am trying to determine the formula for calculating the corrosion rate of a metal in a liquid in relation to the size of electric current that is passed between 2 metal plates. For example: we have 2 aluminium plates in parallel in distilled water at 5 mm distance. The plates are 10 mm thick. The plates are connected to 12V 5A power source. Is it possible to calculate the corrosion rate of the plates in relation to the current?

Comment: This appears to be what we used to call a homework question. You might amend your query to include what your thoughts are on the answer.

Comment: It is certainly possible to calculate the corrosion rate, with the caveat that the current that actually passes through the cell must be measured. Using a 12 V 5 A power source does not mean that 5 A is the current that will go through the cell, only that the current will not exceed 5 A.

Comment: It is more of a home project type of thing. I realize that the current we want is the one that passes between the plates, however I was hoping this can be calculated in advance given the stated parameters (update: I realize you would need to know the resistance of the liquid). Ok, lets assume the current passed between them is 3A. I am not looking for actual calculations. I am more after the formula it self or a pointer where I can find one (or deduce it). The example was just to help to illustrate what kind of set-up I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to calculate the corrosion rate, assuming the current is measured and you can assume all of the current is going into oxidizing the aluminum (which is probably not a safe assumption in most cases), simply based on the amount of charge that is passed.
Charge is the number of electrons being passed and current is charge per unit time.
Therefore, if you know the current, you can calculate the rate of reaction.

If we take one form of Faraday's law of electrolysis:
$$n = \frac{It}{zF}$$ where n is the number of moles of product produced, I is current, t is time, z is the number of electrons transferred per reaction and F is the faraday constant (number of coulombs per mole of electrons), we can simply divide both sides by t to get the number of moles per unit time, i.e. the rate:

$$\frac{n}{t} = \frac{I}{zF}$$

Assuming a 3-electron process ($\ce{Al -> Al^{3+} +3e-}$, for example) with 3 A of current, this works out to around 10 mmol/s (you could convert this to mass or volume using Al's molar mass and density, if you like).

The real trouble in doing something like this is that determining the current *a priori* is not trivial.
In a cell like the one you describe, many factors need to be taken into account.
Here are a few off the top of my head:

- The area of the electrodes in the solution; more area generally means more current.
- The rate of the reaction depends on the electron transfer rate, as well as things like mass transport, if oxygen or the like needs to get to the surface. N.B. the limiting reaction may actually be at the cathode.
- Not all of the current will go into causing the corrosion of the aluminum, some will be lost to producing heat, for instance.
- Depending on the voltage, other electrochemical reactions might occur
- The current will probably change significantly over time. Starting in a very resistive solution like distilled water, the current will be low, but if ions are being produced by the electrodes, the solution will become more conductive over time. (if it's very pure water, this can be very slow)
  I'm not sure if it works in distilled water, but you may also end up with something akin to the process of anodizing aluminum, where oxygen being produced at the anode reacts with the aluminum ions and forming an aluminum oxide layer. Depending on the conditions, this can passivate the electrode and essentially make it non-conductive.

If you are interested in some of the analytical techniques used to examine these properties experimentally, [this primer from Gamry](https://www.gamry.com/application-notes/corrosion-coatings/basics-of-electrochemical-corrosion-measurements/) is quite nice.

In short, it's not really practical to calculate a corrosion rate in advance, especially with just a normal power supply where you can't compensate for the effects of solution resistance and the like, though it may be possible to tune the conditions of your cell such that the current reaches some consistent state over a period of time. (e.g. anodizing aluminum is often done in acidic conditions to dissolve some of the forming oxide layer, to avoid passivating the electrode)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. When I did my research online I had hard time figuring out exactly what to look for but this is gives me a good starting point.  It seems I forgot a lot of stuff from my school days.